# Is it possible to transfer data via rtmp?

Tags: rtmp

I am building a project which requires constant connection with the server.
There are two major ways to achieve this:

- Ajax pull
- Ajax push

I have to decide between pinging a server (expensive) and maintaining keep-alive connections (firewalls block that.)

I was thinking about the live video streams. They are not keep-alive connections, nor frequent pings.

Is it possible, to send data, like JSON strings through rtmp?

Answer (score 1):

It would be theoretically possible to implement RTMP's AMF3 and AMF0 Message types to carry the data. [RTMP [Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)

The problem is that using a protocol typically used for streaming video might get your connection blocked or throttled by some service providers that limit such protocols to conserve bandwidth (and prevent employees from watching internet videos at work).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this article](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/) may be of some use to you. It explains how to set up an [RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol) server with [nginx](http://nginx.com).

*From the article*:

> nginx is an extremely lightweight web server, but someone wrote a RTMP module for it, so it can host RTMP streams too. However, to add the RTMP module, we have to compile nginx from source rather than use the apt package. Don't worry, it's really easy. Just follow these instructions. :)

One comment on this article by a user named 'stefaniuk' linked to a github respitory for this that I think you should look in to. Check it out [here](https://github.com/codeworksio/docker-streaming-server#docker-streaming-server).